# Unity C# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game that is like snake. In my code below, each segment of the snake's body is an instance of the Character class. When I try to add a new character, I get the error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index
```

Other resources online have proposed that there's a List that is empty that I'm trying to reference. But I don't see any evidence of that case in my code.

Perhaps someone smarter than myself can find what I've done wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

/*
 * This class controls the entire snake. The snake has a list 
 * of segments that are each a character. We can move along the snake
 * by moving the characters bottom up, so that the character replaces
 * the position of the character before him.
 */

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

//how many units will he move per 'frame'
public float moveUnits = 1;
//how often he will move (every quarter second)
public float moveTimer = 0.25f;
private float timeSinceLastMoved;
public KeyCode dir = KeyCode.RightArrow;
//locations of boundaries
public float topBoundary = 4.5f;
public float bottomBoundary = -4.5f;
public float leftBoundary = -8.5f;
public float rightBoundary = 8.5f;
//Holds all characters for the snake body
public List<Character> chars = new List<Character>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    timeSinceLastMoved = Time.time;
    getFirstCharacter ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    getInput ();

    if (timeSinceLastMoved + moveTimer < Time.time) {
        move ();
        timeSinceLastMoved = Time.time;
    }

}

void getInput() {

    //if i press right go right, but i can't be going left when i want to go right
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow) && dir != KeyCode.LeftArrow) {
        dir = KeyCode.RightArrow;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow) && dir != KeyCode.RightArrow) {
        dir = KeyCode.LeftArrow;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow) && dir != KeyCode.DownArrow) {
        dir = KeyCode.UpArrow;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow) && dir != KeyCode.UpArrow) {
        dir = KeyCode.DownArrow;
    } 

    //for testing character addition
    else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        addCharacter ();
    }


}

void move() {

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    if (chars.Count != 0) {

        //moves the transform in the appropriate directions
        switch (dir) {
        case KeyCode.RightArrow:
            x = transform.position.x + moveUnits;
            y = transform.position.y;
            break;
        case KeyCode.LeftArrow:
            x = transform.position.x - moveUnits;
            y = transform.position.y;
            break;
        case KeyCode.UpArrow:
            x = transform.position.x;
            y = transform.position.y + moveUnits;
            break;
        case KeyCode.DownArrow:
            x = transform.position.x;
            y = transform.position.y - moveUnits;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        //prevents him from moving outside the set boundaries
        x = Mathf.Clamp (x, leftBoundary, rightBoundary);
        y = Mathf.Clamp (y, bottomBoundary, topBoundary);
        Vector2 pos = new Vector2 (x, y);
        //this moves the whole snake
        transform.position = pos;
        //this moves the first snake segment
        chars[0].transform.position = pos;

        //for all characters(aka snake segments)
        //take the position of the segment before you
        for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i > 0; i++) {
            chars [i].transform.position = chars [i - 1].transform.position;
        }
    }

}

void addCharacter() {
    //the position of the last segment
    Vector2 prevCharPos = chars[chars.Count-1].transform.position;
    Vector2 pos;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    switch (dir) {
    case KeyCode.RightArrow:
        x = prevCharPos.x - moveUnits;
        y = prevCharPos.y;
        break;
    case KeyCode.LeftArrow:
        x = prevCharPos.x + moveUnits;
        y = prevCharPos.y;;
        break;
    case KeyCode.UpArrow:
        x = prevCharPos.x;
        y = prevCharPos.y + moveUnits;
        break;
    case KeyCode.DownArrow:
        x = prevCharPos.x;
        y = prevCharPos.y - moveUnits;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    pos = new Vector2 (x, y);
    //make a new character at the position behind the last segment
    Character newChar = Instantiate (chars[chars.Count - 1], pos, Quaternion.identity, this.transform);
    //add him to the list
    chars.Add (newChar);
}

void getFirstCharacter() {
    //find the character that already exists and add him to the list
    GameObject firstChar = GameObject.Find ("Character");
    if (firstChar != null) {
        chars.Add(firstChar.GetComponent<Character>());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hope that it is not your first post, and you know how to ask a question. then why this much of unnecessary lines of codes?

Comment: What line you get that exception? Debugging to that point me help you to understand the cause of problem!

Comment: Can you tell us which line you are getting the error?

Comment: Just my intuition - check this line if you are playing with for loop correctly?


for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i > 0; i++) {
            chars [i].transform.position = chars [i - 1].transform.position;

Comment: Looks like error is at line `Character newChar = Instantiate (chars[chars.Count - 1], pos, Quaternion.identity, this.transform);` in `addCharacter`method. `chars[chars.Count -1]` will throw exception if `char.Count` is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your FOR loop condition. Theoretically, it will throw out of range exception.

`for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i > 0; i++)
   chars [i].transform.position = chars [i - 1].transform.position;`

I believe your intent should be

`for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

Just put you for loop inside an if check

```
            if(chars.Count>0){
            //for all characters(aka snake segments)
                    //take the position of the segment before you
                    for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i > 0; i++) {
                        chars [i].transform.position = chars [i - 1].transform.position;
                    }
            }
            else{
               Debug.Log("Warning:: chars Count is less than 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN documentation [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is :

> The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside
>   the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method

Which means, the exception will raise when you tried to access an item from a collection based on its index value but actually that index is not within the range of indices. most of the cases collections follows `0` based indexing so if your specific value is below `0` or it is greater than the number of elements in the collection will lead to this exception while accessing.

When we goes through the given snippet, we can see that you have used `chars [i - 1]` in different places, obviously this will cause Exception when value of `i` is `0`.

In short we can say that, Let `chars` be a collection and you are accessing the items based on index, it is important to check `chars.Count > 0` if you are accessing a previous item  using `i-1` and also the loop limit should be less than `chars.Count`.

This may be a generalized answer, but hope that it helps you to understand the reason for this error and how to solve them